# Replacing innerhtml for a specific div that shares the same id as other divs?

Tags: html, onclick, innerhtml

So I've done quite a bit of research and still haven't got this to work.  I am trying to replace the innerhtml of a div.  I have successfully got this to work with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var embedCode = 'new html goes here';
</script>


<div id="videocontainer">
<img class="playButton" onclick="document.getElementById(videocontainer).innerHTML = embedCode;return false;" src=""/>
</div>
```

This is basically a post template which I will copy and paste and only change the images/embedCode.  All works if I have just 1 post.  But once I add another post, both will not work since they both are sharing the same embedCod name and the same div id.  Is there a solution around this without using jQuery?

I've tried using

`document.getElementById(this.id).innerHTML = embedCode`

instead of

`document.getElementById(videocontainer).innerHTML = embedCode`

but its still not working.  Thanks.

Comment: `id` is supposed to be unique. Just increment a counter or use the post ID as part of the `id` attribute.

Comment: Maybe use quotations `document.getElementById("videocontainer").innerHTML = //etc`

Comment: @MarkParnell - If I were to use the post ID as part of the id attribute, then how would I change the css for each id?  Should I just add the css to the line like so <div id="thisPostId" style="same css goes here">  That way I can just copy and paste the same text as my blog continues to grow?

Comment: So I'm trying to use Mark's suggestion but I am now running into a css issue.  The image css needs to be the same for each post.  I am currently using #divID .imageClass {style} in my css.  Since the divID is now dynamic, all my image css will no longer work.  Is there an easier way to do this rather than dynamically making stylsheets for every single post?

Comment: Nobody has any other solutions?

Comment: @max sorry was offline yesterday. Have added an answer which addresses your CSS issues as well.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is supposed to be unique. Just increment a counter or use the post ID as part of the `id` attribute.

For ease of styling, add a class to them as well, e.g. `<div class="videocontainer" id="videocontainer1">`. Use the class for styling and the id for your JS.